# How many sequences $(i_1,\ldots,i_d)$ of fixed length `d` of positive integers satisfy $\alpha\le i_1+\cdots+i_d\le\beta$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $i\in\mathbb N^d$ and $|i|:=i_1+\cdots+i_n$. How can we calculate the cardinality of the set of all $i$ which satisfy $$\alpha\le|i|\le\beta$$ with given constants $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the number of positive sequences of length $d$, with sum $\le \beta$, and let $A$ be the number of positive sequences of length $d$, with sum $\le \alpha-1$. Then our count is $B-A$.

So all we need is an expression for the number of positive $d$-sequences  which have sum $\le k$.

This is the number of positive sequences of length $d+1$ which have sum *exactly* equal to $k+1$. And this problem is a standard Stars and Bars problem (please see Wikipedia). The answer turns out to be $\binom{k}{d}$.

**Remark:** If we seek non-negative solutions, then the number of $d$-tuples with sum $\le k$ is the number of $(d+1)$-tuples with sum exactly  $k$, which is $\binom{k+d}{d}$.

Comment: And here, we need to set $k=\beta-\alpha+1$, right?

Comment: That is not right. We must set $k=\beta$, to calculate the number I called $B$. Then we set $k=\alpha-1$ to calculate the number I called $A$. Finally, we calculate $B-A$.

Comment: Suppose $i_k\in\mathbb N_0$ and $d=2$, $\alpha=0$, $\beta=2$. Then, $$B-A=9\;,$$ but only $$(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0)$$ satisfy the inequality. So, something seems to be wrong.

Comment: I had typo/error. at the end, was quoting Stars and Bars for $\ge 0$.  For $\ge 0$ the correct formula would be $\binom{k+d}{d}$. For $\ge 1$, which is what your question is about, (positive integers), it is something else. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality is equal 
$$
[z^\beta]\frac{1}{(1-z^{i_1})(1-z^{i_2})\cdots(1-z^{i_n}) }-[z^\alpha]\frac{1}{(1-z^{i_1})(1-z^{i_2})\cdots(1-z^{i_n}) },
$$
where $[z^k] F(z)$  is the coefficient of $z^k$  in $F(z).$